# CSS float 3 div columns rendering inconsistent, depends on screen size

Tags: html, css

What is the expected behaviour of the following?

```
<div id="navi" style="float:left;width:230px">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>

<div id="content" style="float: left">
    <div id="diagram" style="float: right"><img src="..." /></div>

    <div id="text">
     <h1>...</h1>
     <h2>...</h2>
     <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a 2 column page with a nested 3rd column in the content div floating to the right to show a diagram image.

However, the browsers rendering for all chrome, ff and ie seems to be inconsistent. Since the `<p>` content is a lot, it can fill a wide space even on a 24" wide screen. Depending on which monitor/resolution I open the browser in, the browser may either render 3 columns (desired) or the navi on top and the content div below with the text and diagram side by side.

How can I make it consistently show 3 columns without using a table and have the text div have "fluid/spring width"? preferably just div and css positioning.

Comment: Would it help to take the right-floating div out of the left-floating div and place it underneath instead? Just thinking out loud.

Comment: Wow, your thoughts can press keys too. Impressive.

Comment: @Mr Lister that will just make the img go to the bottom of the page. I think the problem is really to do with the very wide `<p>`. If I resize the browser so wide it fills both my dual monitors, it will fit the `<p>` and render 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign width as a percentage (you can always use even min-width for set the minimum width of the page and avoid wrong views)

Comment: before i try it out... what percentage do I set it to since I want it to fill as much space as possible. Also, shouldn't it be a max-width in this case because the browser is trying to render the `<p>` as wide as possible.

Comment: The total width (the sum of the width of the 3 columns) must be 100%. So you can assign: "widthDIV1 = 25%, widthDIV2 = 50%, widthDIV3 = 25%". In min-width, instead, I suggest you to assign "min-width: 980px;" to the container.

Comment: Is there no css that says style="width: fill-what-ever-is-left-in-that-100%";? I want to fix the width of the navi so the content div cannot be a fixed %.

Comment: Maybe there is an easier way, but this is the only i see: you can write something like this:
<body style="width: 100%; min-width: 980px;">
  <div class="nav" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; float: left; position: absolute; background: yellow;"></div>
  <div class="contents" style="width: 100%; float: left; padding-left: 200px; height: 100px; background: blue;"></div>
</body>

It works

Comment: argh... the nav is nowhere to be found in ie9. =(

Comment: Add "left: 0;" to its style, try it. I don't use IE9, I can't try it :S

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this is what you want to achieve please view it at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/concypt/qb7NZ/)

Comment: it's sort of what I want, but seems not ideal since the navi div is not fixed width.